# YouTube API Player no longer works on Safari

Tags: javascript, safari, youtube-api

I created a custom skin to play YouTube videos. It used to work in all major browsers. It now no longer works on Safari for desktop computers. Here is the link:

http://www.don-nan.net/gas_separator.php

The console logs an error that says "Error: Error calling method on NPObject"

The error is caused by ytplayer.playVideo() on line 100 of http://www.don-nan.net/chromeless.css. The script works fine in Firefox and Chrome.

Comment: Were you able to make any progress on this? As I noted below, I filed a bug report, but I haven't found any workarounds.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Jamie received the answer for this one. Thank you, Jamie:

https://code.google.com/p/gdata-issues/issues/detail?id=4887

I changed the function called loadPlayer.  Previously, the function looked like:

```
// The "main method" of this sample. Called when someone clicks "Run".
function loadPlayer() {

   // Lets Flash from another domain call JavaScript
   var params = { allowScriptAccess: "always", wmode: "transparent" };

   // The element id of the Flash embed
   var atts = { id: "ytPlayer" };

   // All of the magic handled by SWFObject (http://code.google.com/p/swfobject/)
   swfobject.embedSWF("http://www.youtube.com/apiplayer?" +
       "&enablejsapi=1&playerapiid=player1",
}
```

As the comment at the bottom of the forum states the version number must be passed as a parameter in the url. Therefore, changing this line:

```
swfobject.embedSWF("http://www.youtube.com/apiplayer?" +
```

to:

```
swfobject.embedSWF("http://www.youtube.com/apiplayer?version=3" +
```

fixed the issue.

Answer (score 0):

I'm experiencing the exact same problem, and I've tracked it a little further.

In Safari, my embeds of "//www.youtube.com/apiplayer…" end up showing as https requests in the inspector, even though my page is served over http. Even if I explicitly specify that the scheme should be http ("http://www.youtube.com/apiplayer…"), I see https requests instead. I presume this triggers a mixed-mode security issue that causes the NPObject errors.

The same thing is happening on your site.

Here's the simplest example:

```
<html>
<body>
    <object type="application/x-shockwave-flash"
            data="http://www.youtube.com/apiplayer">
    </object>
</body>
</html>
```

That fires off http requests to www.youtube.com and s.ytimg.com in Chrome, but I see https requests instead in Safari.

Yet it doesn't happen with other players I tried:

```
http://vimeo.com/moogaloop.swf
http://www.viddler.com/player/key
```

Nor does it happen if I change the User-Agent to something other than Safari!

Comment: I've reported the issue: [https://code.google.com/p/gdata-issues/issues/detail?id=4887](https://code.google.com/p/gdata-issues/issues/detail?id=4887)